# Swift: Update TableView Data in PageView Using Slider

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5

I have a project with a main view controller and a page view controller which are both always visible (see image)[image]

The main view controller contains a slider and the page view controller containts several pages each with an instance of table view.  View controllers:

- DataViewController: for pageview data
- TableViewCell (including xib): to build the table view cell
- MainViewController: for main view, containing slider

My question is how do I update the table view in my page views in realtime as the user adjusts the slider in MainViewController.  My code:

In TableViewCell:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var outputLabel: UILabel!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }
    
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
    
    class var reuseIdentifier: String {
        return "IngredientCell"
    }
    
    class var nibName: String {
        return "IngredientTableViewCell"
    }
    
    func configureResultCell(text: String) {
        outputLabel.text = text
    }
```

In DataViewController:

```
...
    var results: [String]?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        registerNib()
    }

...
}

extension DataViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if let int = results?.count {
            return int
        }
        return 0
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        print("cellforrowat", results)
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: IngredientTableViewCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? IngredientTableViewCell {
            if let text = results?[indexPath.row] {
                cell.configureResultCell(text: text)
            }
            return cell
        }
        
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
    
}
```

In MainViewController:

```
    @IBAction func sliderValueChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
        
        guard let dataViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: String(describing: DataViewController.self)) as? DataViewController else {
            return
        }
        
        dataViewController.results = [NEW_VALUES]
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            dataViewController.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        
    }
```

Basically, the table view in DataViewController doesn't update with the new values.  Any advice appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your mistake is in `MainViewController` method: `sliderValueChanged` . You see every time you adjust the slider you instantiate (create) a new instance of the `DataViewController`. In order to work as you expect you have to save the instance of the presented `DataViewController` and use this instance instead of creating a new one every time.

In order to achieve this I recommend you to use the delegation pattern, reference here: https://learnappmaking.com/delegation-swift-how-to/. This pattern will help you safely establish a "communication" between the two View Controllers.

Comment: @DialDT if my answer helped you please mark as the accepted answer in order to help more people with the same question. Thanks